# How to prevent the oldVersion in a bindingRedirect being overwritten when bindingRedirect is added via Nuget

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, visual-studio-2013, nuget-package

I have created an assembly that relies on additional third party assemblies which may or may not be in the project references at the time that my assembly is added. Because my assembly was originally built using the third party dependencies that may have been older than those that are in the current project I need to add bindingRedirects to the app.config file.  A fellow Stack Overflow contributor (in answer to a question of mine about whether it would be possible to somehow automate the amendment required to the app.config file) suggested that I look at distributing my assembly via NuGet.  This turned out to be a great suggestion, but I am noticing one odd effect and I don't know how I could correct it, if at all.

In the content folder of my NuGet package I have an app.config.transform file, which is ostensibly like this:

```
<configuration>
 <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="C1.Win.C1Ribbon.2" culture="neutral" publicKeyToken="79882d576c6336da"/>
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="2.0.20141.567" newVersion="Add New Value Here"/>
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
</configuration>
```

There are other redirects but this ought to be sufficient for you to get the gist.

When I add the NuGet package to a project it loads my assembly and alters the app.config file, a result, but as is so often the case with programming things never quite seem to run to plan.

If one of the assemblies for which I have provided redirects is already present in the project then some subtle changes get made to the original xml that I had supplied in the NuGet Package:

```
<configuration>
<runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="C1.Win.C1Ribbon.2" culture="neutral" publicKeyToken="79882d576c6336da" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-2.0.20142.582" newVersion="2.0.20142.582" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
</configuration>
```

You'll notice that the oldVersion has been completely changed and the newVersion has been amended to reflect the current version oof the assembly that is in the projects references.  From my point of view the automatic change to the newVersion is as added bonus as it's something that the end user won't need to do, HOWEVER the change to the oldVersion is a complete disaster as the project will now throw errors when compiled.

How can I prevent the oldVersion details from being overwritten if the assembly happens to be present when the nuget package is added to the project?

Comment: Well one way around this, and the only one I can think of for the time being is to add a comment line above the bindingRedirect line pointing out exactly what the oldVersion should be. This is what I have done for present but I'd still like to know why it is getting reset and what it might be possible to do to avoid it.

Answer (score 2):

You are really on the wrong track here, that "oldVersion" attribute is not the source of your problems.  The trouble got started by you taking a dependency on somebody else's library.  Libraries change, it is inevitable.  And such a change can, *and will*, break your program sooner or later.  Sooner in this case.

The library author does use a very poor practice.  A version number like "2.0.20142.582" is  meaningless.  It is an *auto-generated* version number.  You can look at such a number and have absolutely no idea how impactful the change in the library might be.  A common complaint about version numbers and many library authors have switched to *semantic versioning*.  A simpler version number: x.y.z.  Where an increment in z is just a minor maintenance increment that you don't worry about.  An increment in y makes you pay attention, you read the release notes to see if there's a need to revise or improve your own code.  An increment in x spells lots of trouble.

Nuget packages tinker with `<bindingRedirect>` to try to make their version number changes not break your program.  Somewhat inevitably, because the author used such a poor version numbering scheme, his bindingRedirect is meaningless.  He states that his new library is compatible with *all* the previous versions of his library.  A complete lie, as you found out.

You'll have to choose whether or not to skip this library update.  If you don't then you *have* to fix the compile errors that the new version caused.  No two ways about it.  The "oldVersion" attribute does not matter at all, you made your program compatible with the current version.  You might as well completely remove the bindingRedirect, it is meaningless.

Comment: Hans, you're quite right to say that the problem started by taking on a dependency on a third party, but my assembly was designed to 'add value' if you like to one aspect of their assemblies. A dependency therefore was always going to be on the cards. However, purely for the sake of clarification their version numbers are structured.  I genuinely appreciate the assistance you have provided me in your answers to the questions I've posed about this.  I guess I'm hampered as much by my own lack of knowledge as anything else, but how else do we learn?